# How to make a column a running total in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table for input to a **chart programme** for display. The columns are Date(daily), `Algo52` and `Algo51` and the rows are by date. I did get it to work with just daily results. Here is that query:

```
SELECT

BptChart.BptChartDate,
SUM(IF(q.Algo='53',q.PipTotals,0)) As Algo53,
SUM(IF(q.Algo='52',q.PipTotals,0)) As Algo52

FROM (

SELECT

BptAlgo.BptAccountID As Algo,
DATE(BptAlgo.CloseTime) As TradeDate,
SUM(CAST(BptAlgo.Pips AS DECIMAL(7,2))) AS PipTotals

FROM BptAlgo
INNER JOIN BptAccount ON BptAccount.BptAccountID = BptAlgo.BptAccountID
WHERE BptAlgo.Status = 'CLOSED' AND BptAlgo.CloseTime > '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AND BptAccount.Status = 'OPEN'
GROUP BY YEAR(TradeDate), MONTH(TradeDate), DAY(TradeDate), BptAlgo.BptAccountID
ORDER BY CloseTime DESC 
LIMIT 1500

) q

INNER JOIN BptChart ON q.TradeDate = BptChart.BptChartDate
GROUP BY YEAR(BptChart.BptChartDate), MONTH(BptChart.BptChartDate), 
DAY(BptChart.BptChartDate)
ORDER BY BptChart.BptChartDate ASC
```

What I want now is to have running totals not just the daily results. Here is the query I tried:

```
SELECT

BptChart.BptChartDate,
(@runtot53 := @runtot53 + (SUM(IF(q.Algo='53',q.PipTotals,0)))) As Algo53,
(@runtot52 := @runtot52 + (SUM(IF(q.Algo='52',q.PipTotals,0)))) As Algo52

FROM (

(SELECT

BptAlgo.BptAccountID As Algo,
DATE(BptAlgo.CloseTime) As TradeDate,
SUM(CAST(BptAlgo.Pips AS DECIMAL(7,2))) AS PipTotals

FROM BptAlgo
INNER JOIN BptAccount ON BptAccount.BptAccountID = BptAlgo.BptAccountID
WHERE BptAlgo.Status = 'CLOSED' AND BptAlgo.CloseTime > '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AND BptAccount.Status = 'OPEN'
GROUP BY YEAR(TradeDate), MONTH(TradeDate), DAY(TradeDate), BptAlgo.BptAccountID
ORDER BY CloseTime DESC 
LIMIT 1500

) q,

(SELECT @runtot53:=0) n53,
(SELECT @runtot52:=0) n52

)

INNER JOIN BptChart ON q.TradeDate = BptChart.BptChartDate
GROUP BY YEAR(BptChart.BptChartDate), MONTH(BptChart.BptChartDate), 
DAY(BptChart.BptChartDate)
ORDER BY BptChart.BptChartDate ASC
```

It does not work, as it does not give me the running totals, it gives the same results as the original. I think the variables are getting reset to 0 on each row. But not sure. Note: The chart package allows only one query for the input, so no SET statements are allowed.

Any ideas on what I can do here?

Comment: This looks wildly over-complicated if you're just trying to total certain things. Can you simplify this in any way to better explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes it looks simple until you get into it. One needs to first select the limit data (newest data) then resort for proper display (start display on the oldest record). One also needs to pivot the table to allow the chart package to take the data in proper fashion. In addition one must account for zero days, hence the join to BptChart.BptChartDate which is just a table with all valid dates.

Comment: Maybe your schema is an obstacle here. Would there be a better way to organize the data to get the reports you need?

Comment: schema can not be changed, as the package and data are legacy. So one has to work with what you got.

Comment: Don't forget you can temporarily alter the schema by using a sub-select to restructure it in a format that's easier to work with, or by using a view.

Comment: Maybe see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query